How does this solution involving complex numbers work on this inequality?
I would like to have an explanation of the following solution to the following problem (instead of another solution), and a similar problem has been asked by me before.

Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$ be real numbers such that
$$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+a_4a_5+a_5a_1=20,\\a_1a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_5+a_4a_1+a_5a_2=24.$$
Prove that $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2+a_5^2\ge22+2\sqrt5$.

The solution defined $z_i=\frac1{\sqrt5}\sum\limits_{k=1}^5a_k\omega^{-ki}$, but it did not state what $\omega$ was, perhaps $\mathrm e^{\frac{2\pi}3\mathrm i}$.
Then it claimed that
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^5a_i^2&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5|z_i|^2,\\\sum\limits_{i=1}^5a_ia_{i+1}&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\cos\frac{2k\pi}5|z_i|^2,\tag1\\\sum\limits_{i=1}^5a_ia_{i+2}&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\cos\frac{4k\pi}5|z_i|^2.\tag2
\end{align}
I don't understand why any of the equations hold.
Then it finished the proof by considering $2\cos\frac{2\pi}5(1)-2\cos\frac\pi5(2)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^5|z_i|^2$.
Can anyone explain how this solution works?

Choose $\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}$, we verify the three equations.
First equation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^5|z_j|^2&=\frac15\sum_{j=1}^5\left|\sum_{k=1}^5a_k\omega^{-jk}\right|^2\\
&=\frac15\sum_{j=1}^5\sum_{1\leq k,l\leq5}a_ka_l\omega^{j(l-k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^5a_k^2+\frac15\sum_{1\leq k\neq l\leq5}a_ka_l\underbrace{\left(\omega^{l-k}+\omega^{2(l-k)}+\omega^{3(l-k)}+\omega^{4(l-k)}+\omega^{5(l-k)}\right)}_{=\,0}.
\end{align*}
Second equation:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{j=1}^5\cos\left(\frac{2j\pi}5\right)|z_j|^2=\text{Re}\sum_{j=1}^5\omega^j|z_j|^2\\
&=\frac15\text{Re}\sum_{j=1}^5\sum_{1\leq k,l\leq5}a_ka_l\omega^{j(l-k-1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^5a_ka_{k+1}+\frac15\text{Re}\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{1\leq k,l\leq5\\l-k\not\equiv1\ \text{mod}\ 5}}\!\!\!\!\!a_ka_l\underbrace{\left(\omega^{l-k-1}+\omega^{2(l-k-1)}+\omega^{3(l-k-1)}+\omega^{4(l-k-1)}+\omega^{5(l-k-1)}\right)}_{=\,0}.
\end{align*}
Third equation is similar (replacing $\omega^j$ with $\omega^{2j}$).
Now with $(1),(2)$ denoting the second and third equation respectively, we have
\begin{align*}
&2\cos\frac{2\pi}5(1)-2\cos\frac\pi5(2)+\sum\limits_{j=1}^5|z_j|^2\\
=\ &\sum_{j=1}^5\underbrace{\left(2\cos\frac{2\pi}5\cos\frac{2j\pi}5-2\cos\frac\pi5\cos\frac{4j\pi}5+1\right)}_{=\ A_j}|z_j|^2.
\end{align*}
Using trigonometry identities, we get
$$A_j=\frac{\sqrt5-1}2\cos\frac{2j\pi}5-\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\cos\frac{4j\pi}5+1$$
where $j=1,2,...,5$. It is easy to show $A_j$ is minimised when $j=2$, with $A_2=0$. Hence $A_j\geq0$ and
$$\sum_{j=1}^5a_j^2=\sum_{j=1}^5|z_j|^2\geq2\cos\frac\pi5(2)-2\cos\frac{2\pi}5(1)=22+2\sqrt5.$$

Probably the unique and perfect! This method might be called the theory of unit root filter?

@MathArt Thanks! Yes sometimes it's called root of unity filter
